# Prove set where limit of sequence of measurable functions exists is F-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm working through Koralov's book on probability on my own and having some difficulty with problem 3.9.1:

*Let $f_n$ and $f$ be measurable functions on a measurable space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Prove that the set $\{ \omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(\omega) = f(\omega) \}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.
Prove that the set $\{ \omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(\omega) exists \}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context for sure, but it seems safe to assume these functions are real-valued (or maybe complex-valued).  However, you definitely can't assume $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in any sense.  For any particular value of $\omega$, the sequence $(f_n(\omega))$ may not converge at all.  The problem is asking you to think about the set of all $\omega$ such that it *does* converge (in the first question, to $f(\omega)$, and in the second question, to anything).  For $\omega$ such that $(f_n(\omega))$ converges it will be a Cauchy sequence, but you don't know that it actually ever does converge.